# Enable the button if there is input in the TextField SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

For the first time to question. I'm sorry if I'm rude.

I want to create a mechanism that prevents the button from being pressed when there is no input in the TextField. On the contrary, I want to enable the button if there is input.

I wrote it like this, but I get an error saying "Cannot find'$ task' in scope".

### Do you know why?

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
 
struct TFenableView: View {
  @ObservedObject var task: Task
   
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
   
  var taskNameIsValid: Bool {
    return !task.name.isEmpty
  }
   
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      TextField("Edit TaskName", text: $task.name)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        .padding()
       
      Button(action: {
        Task.save(in: self.viewContext)
        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      }) {
        Text("Update!")
      }.padding()
        .disabled(!taskNameIsValid)
      }
    .navigationBarTitle("Editing screen")
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(!taskNameIsValid)
  }
}

struct TFenableVieew_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TFenableView()
    }
}
```

[TextField photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB7P8.png)

Comment: Note `Task` is already a swift 5.5 struct name. 
Can you show the code for your `Task class`.
Also you have a typo in `TFenableVieew_Previews` and you are missing 
`TFenableView(task: Task())` in that.

Comment: Works for me, when I make changes to get it compiling & working. For the compiler error, try clean (`command + shift + K`) & rebuild the project.